# SetWindowText не меняет свойство контрола

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

WinAPI метод SetWindowText не меняет текст кнопки. Причем, если попробовать получить текст через GetWindowText, то вернется, как раз, тот текст, который я пытался задать, а не отображаемый по факту. Забавно, но заголовок формы меняется, в отличии от кнопки, вызов метода из другого потока (с выключенным CheckForIlligalCross) и Invalidate кнопки ожидаемо не дают результата.

Upd. Примеры кода:

Класс WinAPI

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetWindowText(HandleRef hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpString);
```

Класс Window

```
public static Window Find(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    return new Window()
    {
        Handle = hwnd
    };
}

public string GetText()
{
    int capacity = WinAPI.GetWindowTextLength(new HandleRef(this, Handle)) * 2;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(capacity);
    WinAPI.GetWindowText(new HandleRef(this, Handle), stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity);
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}

public bool SetText(string text)
{
    return WinAPI.SetWindowText(Handle, text);
}
```

Код формы:

```
button1.Click += (s, e) =>
{
    var btn = Window.Find(button1.Handle);
    btn.SetText("hello");
    MessageBox.Show(btn.GetText());
};
```

Результат на скрине.

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Покажите ваш код, а лучше [mcve].

Comment: Обновил. Извиняюсь за немного избыточный код, но все происходит аж в двух проектах.

Comment: `btn.SetText("hello");` - где `Button.SetText`?

Comment: Немного не понял замечания, можете подробнее изложить?